# Finding if user has already add it in their reminder collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 database tables and 3 models and relations between them.
The database tables are: `feed_entries`, `users`, `reminders`.

- `User` and `FeedEntry` has many reminders
- `Reminder` belongs to `User` and `FeedEntry`.

I have a button called **read later**, and when user clicks on it, it saves the record to the `reminders` table. On the `/user/reminders` page, I display all the links/records that user wanted to "read later".

Everything until now works fine. However, I want to "hide/remove" the **read later** button for records/links that users has already added it into their reminder collection.

View code:

```
#recent_episodes
  %h2 Send me to random news
  %p= link_to "Send me to random news", article_path(@random), class: "btn btn-info"
  %hr
  %h3 Feeds
  #products
    .row
      - @entries.each do |entry|
        .col-md-12
          = link_to h(entry.name), article_path(entry)
          - if entry.summary.blank?
            %p no summary
          - else
            %p= sanitize entry.summary
          %p
            = link_to 'Link', entry.url, target: "_blank"
            %span - Views #{entry.hits}
            %p= entry.source

          %p Points #{entry.cached_votes_total}
          .btn-group
            = link_to like_article_path(entry), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do
              %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-up
              Upvote
              \#{entry.get_upvotes.size}
            = link_to dislike_article_path(entry), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do
              %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-down
                Downvote
                \#{entry.get_downvotes.size}

          - if user_signed_in?
              = simple_form_for [@reminder, Reminder.new]  do |f|
                .form-group
                  = hidden_field :user_id,  :user_id, :value => current_user.id

                .form-group
                  = f.label :feed_entry_id
                  = f.text_field :feed_entry_id, :value => entry.id

                .form-group
                  = f.submit "read later", class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary"

          %hr

      = paginate @entries
```

Any clues I can fix it is much appreciate.

Comment: Please post your View code, so we can see how you are rendering the link you want to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct way to do it is create a new method on User like:

```
def has_reminder?(feed_entry)
  reminders.where(feed_entry: feed_entry).any?
end
```

And in your view do:

```
<%= link_to_unless(@current_user.has_reminder?(feed_entry), "Read Later", ...) %>
```